# Let $T$ be a normal random variable that describes the temperature...

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $T$ be a normal random variable that describes the temperature in Rome
on the 2nd of June. It is known that on this date the average temperature is equal to $µ_T = 20$ centigrade degrees and that $P (T ≤ 25) = 0.8212$.

How can I calculate the variance of $T$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $P(T \leq 25)=0.8212$, you can find the $z$-score of $25$ (reverse-lookup in a $z$-score table).

The $z$-score of $25$ is also given by $z=\frac{25-\mu_T}{\sigma}$.

Set these two expressions for the $z$-score equal to each other and solve for $\sigma$. Finally, square it to get $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Ok, so the z-score is 0,92?

Comment: @user675557  Yes, that's it.

Comment: @bob.sacamento I have to put 0.92 equal to the z equation?

Comment: Yes.  Since you found the z score, you know $0.92 = (25-\mu_T)/\sigma$.  You already know $\mu_T$, and $\sigma$ is what you are trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the standard version of $T$,
$$\Pr(Z \leq \alpha) = 0.8212$$
where we subtract by the mean and divide by standard deviation $\sigma$, as 
$$\Pr(T \leq 25) = \Pr(\underbrace{\frac{T - \mu_T}{\sigma}}_Z \leq \underbrace{\frac{25 - 20}{\sigma}}_\alpha) = 0.8212$$
Using the z table, you can easily find $\alpha$, which gives you $\sigma$.